# Gradle cannot compile imported jars from domain classes

Tags: java, gradle, jar, package, exists

I'm trying to import existing jar files from domain package as dependencies into a new Gradle project. But Gradle throws **error: package example_mypackage does not exist.** However, **packages seem to have been imported correctly before build.**

```
 import example_mypackage.MyExample;

 public class Example {

     private String str;

     public Example(String str){
          this.str = str;    
     }

     public String run(){
          return example_mypackage.MyExample.execute(this.str); //Here package cannot recognized by gradle
     }
 }
```

As a result Gradle throws that **errror: package example_mypackage does not exist.**

How can I efficiently import my existing domain classes as a dependency in a new Gradle project ?

Comment: *existing jar files* - how do you tell Gradle where it should find these JARs?

Comment: Solved: the way I produced the jars was wrong!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of jar file should be like this :

```
 ---example.jar
     ---META-INF  
        --- MANIFEST.MF
     ---package_mypackage
        ---MyExample
     ---package_nextpackage
        ----NextExample
```